# Android: screen cropped at bottom when phone at landscape mode

Tags: android, screen

I created screen using eclipse for Android. screen display correctly in portrait mode, but when we mobile rotate to landscape screen area in RelativeLayout cropped. I tried the same by removing RelativeLayout, but all vain.

screen cropped at bottom when phone at landscape mode

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtspace1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/launcher"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtApp_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txt1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" 
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txt2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtspace2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txt3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" 
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtspace3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"

        >
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/txt5"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
          android:text="@string/txt5"
          android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />
       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_above="@+id/txt5"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:text="@string/txt6"
          android:paddingBottom="5dp"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"
          android:paddingRight="5dp"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>*
```

Comment: This is normal behaviour. What do you there to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your whole linearlayout in scrollview. This will fix it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtspace1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/launcher"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtApp_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txt1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" 
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txt2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtspace2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txt3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" 
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtspace3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"

        >
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/txt5"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
          android:text="@string/txt5"
          android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />
       <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_above="@+id/txt5"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:text="@string/txt6"
          android:paddingBottom="5dp"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"
          android:paddingRight="5dp"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is giving. Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Comment: Much better than before, but @+id/textView1 cutting. This text having around 150 characters

Comment: If your scrollview issue is resolved. please post different question for textview issue. Also accept the above answer.

Comment: No issue is not resolve, I questioned initially my RelativeLayout getting cropped, but now @+id/txt5 displays from RelativeLayout  & @+id/textView1 getting cropped

Comment: It did after some correction on code, Thanks for your efforts